# Update row values for same key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two types of id and a value.I need to update all values that are null with the value for the same id.For example

Input

```
aid   no     bid
A      1     1
A      2     NULL
A      3     NULL
B      1     NULL
B      2     2
B      3     NULL
```

In the above table I need to update value 1 for A to all rows with A as key and for B I need update value 2 for all rows with key B.

Output

```
A   1   1
A   2   1
A   3   1
B   1   2
B   2   2
B   3   2
```

I am using a temp table to do this.Is there a simpler way to do this without using temp table?

```
select bid, aid  
into #tempbidNULL 
from table_name 
where bid is null and aid is not null

select bid, aid 
into #tempbidNOTNULL 
from table_name where bid is not null 
 and aid in (select aid from #tempbidNULL)

update table_name 
set bid = b.bid
from table_name x 
join #tempbidNOTNULL y on x.aid = y.aid
where x.bid IS NULL
where y.bid IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: What do you want when you have more than 1 value? What about when you don't have a value? With as much rep as you have you must realize this question is pretty poor. And your "sample" query is not going to run as you claim. You can't have two where clauses on a single query.

Comment: It doesn't have more than 1 value for a given key.NULLS if there is no value.That case is taken care of in the first select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, max(val2) over (partition by col1) as new_val2
      from table_name 
     )
update toupdate
     set val2 = new_val2
     where val2 is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPADTE table_name
SET b_id=CASE a_id WHEN 'A' THEN 1 WHEN 'B' THEN 2 END
WHERE b_id is null AND a_id is not null
```

Comment: I don't think this is going to work the way they want.

Comment: Sorry, the table has more than a million records and values can be anything and is not restricted to 1 and 2

Comment: Then you have a lookup table? In that case it is a simple UPDATE with JOIN situation